# ControlTemplates share the same color

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, arcgis

I'm trying to use this Control Template as a resource to give a polygon a symbol. The user chooses the colour of the polygon when the polygon is created. However when the user creates a new polygon and chooses a different colour is switches to the most recent colour for all the added polygons.

Xaml:

```
<!-- Polygon -->
<esri:SimpleFillSymbol x:Key="KmlPolygonStyle">
    <esri:SimpleFillSymbol.ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate x:Name="CustomKmlPolygonTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Element"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="StrokeThickness"
                                                 To="1" Duration="0:0:0.1"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Element"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.Opacity"
                                                 To="0.5" Duration="0:0:0.1"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Element"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="StrokeThickness"
                                                 To="2" Duration="0:0:0.1"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Element"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.Opacity"
                                                 To="0.7" Duration="0:0:0.1"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Element"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="StrokeThickness"
                                                 To="3" Duration="0:0:0.1"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Element"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.Opacity"
                                                 To="0.9" Duration="0:0:0.1"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <Path x:Name="Element"
                            Fill="{Binding Symbol.Fill}" Stroke="{Binding Symbol.BorderBrush}"
                            StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeThickness="1" 
                            StrokeLineJoin="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </esri:SimpleFillSymbol.ControlTemplate>
</esri:SimpleFillSymbol>
```

C# Code:

```
 var kmlSymbol = Application.Current.Resources["KmlPolygonStyle"] as SimpleFillSymbol;                                                             
 kmlSymbol.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(LayerColorPicker.SelectedColor.Color); 
 kmlSymbol.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(LayerColorPicker.SelectedColor.Color);
 kmlSymbol.BorderThickness = 1;
 kmlSymbol.Fill.Opacity = 0.5;                                                                       
 kmlRenderer.Symbol = kmlSymbol;
```

How can I make each polygon added use the appropriate chosen colour.

Comment: Although the Silverlight version isn't my thing, I'd say your problem is that you're setting the symbol for the layer as a whole (via the line `kmlRenderer.Symbol = kmlSymbol;`). If you're using a `SimpleRenderer` for that layer, that's all you'll ever be able to do - you may need to look at `UniqueValueRenderer`s...?

Comment: there are multiple graphic layers and the problem extends to each and all of them. My guess is that it has something to do with binding to the colours perhaps rather than constructing colours perhaps?

Comment: That sounds reasonable - I'm interpreting that to mean you effectively create a new symbol every time, rather than modifying the same object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing the binding to one time cleared up the problem.

```
              ...     <Path x:Name="Element"
                            Fill="{Binding Symbol.Fill, Mode=OneTime}" Stroke="{Binding Symbol.BorderBrush, Mode=OneTime}"
                            StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeThickness="1" 
                            StrokeLineJoin="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round"/>   ...
```